# Trying to understand why AJAX objects added into DOM return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem when calling a ajax call that after the ajax data is appended into the DOM, any Javascript referring to the appended html returns that the object is undefined.

The forms use  tags with Javascript submits and some Javascript to modify hidden fields, thats why the `eval()` is in there.

**edit:** This is an example of a 'href' tag and why I have the eval in there:

```
javascript:document.faultList.sortBy.value='4';document.faultList.sortByPrev.value='3';document.faultList.Action01.value='SetMyRequestItem';
```

Its how the previous developer has created this software/website before my time instead of using a REST style system.

This is my code:

```
function ajaxFormUpdate(formID,linkClass){
        $(formID+' '+linkClass).click(function(){
            eval($(this).attr('href'));
            serialised = $(this).closest(formID).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'jadehttp.dll?EbdMulti_www_01',
                    data: serialised,
                    success: function(data) {
                        //console.log(data)
                        $(formID).html($(data).find(formID));
                        loadHandlers();
                        }
            });
            return false
        });

    }
    function loadHandlers(){
        ajaxFormUpdate('#faultList','.ajaxLink');
        ajaxFormUpdate('#accessCardList','.ajaxLink');
        ajaxFormUpdate('#facilityList','.ajaxLink');
        ajaxFormUpdate('#carParkingList','.ajaxLink');
        ajaxFormUpdate('#visitorList','.ajaxLink');
    }
    loadHandlers();
```

Comment: 1. Sorry. I still do not understand why the eval is there. 2. If `formID` is an ID you'll just have to use `$(formId)`, since every dom ID must be unique. 3. Do the data really contain the form id?

Comment: Updated why the eval is there, the actual code works first time round and will update the form with the ajax reply, its when I click the link inside the form for the second time that the link will say 'document.faultList.sortBy.value' is undefined, as its a part of the data i update when i do $(formID).html($(data).find(formID));

Comment: The nodes get replaced when you use `.html()` = the click event is  not captured anymore.

Comment: I thought the loadHandlers(); callback would target the new nodes, as the ID's are the same? What would be the best way to target the new nodes after the .html() method clears and inserts new nodes?

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: `$('.ajaxLink').live('click', function() {})` binds to the element when the actual click is made and not before. You can then use  `$(this).closes('form')` to find the parent form.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this by changing `.html()` to `.replaceWith()` (thanks jgauffin for putting me on the right track) and using the following click handler instead of the standard `.click()`

```
$(".selector_class").live('click', function() { alert("new element clicked"); });
```